# There are complex constants $ w_i $ such that a complex polynomial $ F (x) $ is written as a product of terms of the form$ (1-x.w_i)$?

Tags: polynomials

does my book take such a polynomial and assume the validity of this fact, is it a general fact or is there anything particular about the book's polynomial?

Answer (score 1):

Of course the constant term must be $1$ for this to work.  The rest  follows from the [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra).

Comment: so I know the fundamental theorem of algebra speaks in $ (xb_i -1) $